# Create value bases class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create your own value based class?
Example:
String is value based:

```
String name1 = "some string";
String name2 = "some string";
Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<String, Object>;
newMap.put(name1, new Object());
Object obj = map.get(name2);
```

I can get the Object by a `String`, that is technically not the same with which i `put()` it, but it has the same value.
How can I do this with my own class?

Comment: In your example, both `name1` and `name2` are referencing the same object. Are you looking for custom literal syntax? I'm confused.

Comment: Are you talking about overriding hashcode and equals?

Comment: @Aderis Oh, that's not how I read it at all, since `String` isn't a primitive type, but that makes sense now that you point it out.

Comment: I will override hashcode and equals and try it.

Comment: @MyNameIsHans What exactly do you mean by "value based class"?

Comment: Or are you talking about Generic types? `public class MyClass<V>` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: A class whrere it only matters what the variables of it are when its compared to another class

Comment: Then, yes, override `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Do note, however, that nothing you can do will ever make two different objects `==` to each other, even if all their fields are identical.

Comment: Isn't ´equals()´ and ´==´ basically the same thing to compiler?
Edit: it doesn't seem to be..  Didn't know that xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` and variants interpret keys in the same way that the legacy [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) does:

> To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used as keys must implement the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method and the `equals` method.

Assuming you've done that, the [`get(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method works like this:

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>   More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

Comment: Ok. I have overridden equals and hashcode and it works. Thank you.